# NullReferenceException for no reason that I can find

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, loops, if-statement, nullreferenceexception

Here is my issue (and my code). When I run this, it will loop as expected, checking the values, but eventually, when it finds a value that matches up, it will jump the track. (More info after the code)

```
    DevCon = DevCon.ToUpper     'Capitalizing everything
    DevIDLeg = DevIDLeg.ToUpper
    DevIDMod = DevIDMod.ToUpper
    DevIDIris = DevIDIris.ToUpper


    Dim Legacy As String() = DevIDLeg.Split(New Char() {","c})     'Splitting everything by comma's.
    Dim Modern As String() = DevIDMod.Split(New Char() {","c})
    Dim Iris As String() = DevIDIris.Split(New Char() {","c})
    For Count = 0 To 1000 Step 1
        If Count > Legacy.Length = False Then                          'Makes sure we aren't checking more than the all the values that the array can hold
            If DevCon.Contains(Legacy.ElementAt(Count)) = True Then     'Checks to see if the values match
                RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")                      'Creates Key, even if it already exists (no outstanding error)
                RegKey.SetValue("Intel_DEVID", "isLegacy")              'Sets the value of the Key
                RegKey.Close()                                          'Closes the Key
            End If
        End If
        If Count > Modern.Count = False Then                            'Everything from above (the comments) can be repeated.
            If DevCon.Contains(Modern.ElementAt(Count)) = True Then
                RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")
                RegKey.SetValue("Intel_DEVID", "isModern")
                RegKey.Close()
            End If
        End If
        If Count > Iris.Length = False Then
            If DevCon.Contains(Iris.ElementAt(Count)) = True Then
                RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")
                RegKey.SetValue("Intel_DEVID", "isIrisHasswell")
                RegKey.Close()
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Basically, I have 4 text files, one is generated by an external program, and 3 are of expected possible results. Each loop, the program will check each value to see if it is contained in the string generated by the external program.

When it finds one such value (in my case, it will find it in the Value Modern (the second set of IF's in the loop), on the 5th iteration) It will then start executing the code. `RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")`. For some reason, this will cause it to jump to the end of the code, with this error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in DevIDParser.exe

Above everything (in the Dim's) It is Initialized

```
Public RegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Removed\for\reasons", True)
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line

```
RegKey.CreateSubKey("Intel_DEVID")
```

throws a `NullReferenceException`, it means that `RegKey` is Nothing, which means that

```
Public RegKey As RegistryKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Removed\for\reasons", True)
```

failed to open the registry key you requested.

Note the documentation for [`RegistryKey.OpenSubKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/xthy8s8d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> **RegistryKey.OpenSubKey Method (String, Boolean)**
>
> Retrieves a subkey as read-only.
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
>   The subkey requested, or **null** if the operation failed.
>
> **Remarks**
>   If the requested key does not exist, this method returns null instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't adding "true" to the end make it read-write?

Comment: @user3468962 There's a difference between functions `OpenSubKey` and `CreateSubKey`. Otherwise there wouldn't be two functions that do the same thing.

Comment: @user3468962 With the `true` argument, you request write access. But if the key does not exist, it won't create it for you, but rather return `Nothing`. You have to create the key first.

Comment: @Diminic-Kexel In this case, the key already exists. I am just trying to write a value to it. (I realized I didn't need the CreateSubKey part (new to using the registry for storing data), removed it, and it still errors)

Comment: @user3468962 Are you 100% sure the key exists? It doesn't look like that.